# How to make only 1 user login at a time

Tags: php

Hi am constructing an test portal in php. I want that if an user has started the test then he can't login from any other devices. That means logging only once from a particular user while giving test. I thought to accomplish this by setting a row in user table as active with values 1 and 0. When user starts test active is 1 but when he ends active is 0.When active is 1 user is logged in and no other person can login from the same id. But suppose user's internet connection is lost then the active state will be 1 only. And he cant login again if internet disconnects. Please help me how to accomplish this ?

Comment: If a user log in and not logging out, what will you do?? If the user internet disconnects?? If trying login simultaneously?? You need to take care of all these.

Comment: I elaborated my idea. I know the problem with this approach. Thatswhy i am asking

Comment: I think you should use sessions. If session times out, reset the flag you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea, but make sure to include a timestamp to show when the active user logged in. That way if their connection is lost and they try to login again at a later time from a different device you can check the timestamp to see that a reasonable amount of time has passed, and allow the new login from the different device.

If you expect users to be active on the site for long periods of time, it might be safer to update the timestamp every time the logged-in user performs an action on the site (such as viewing a page or posting data) so that another user cannot login while the first user is active, even if the first user has been logged-in for a long time.